# Laravel Eloquent no primary key

Tags: laravel, eloquent, primary-key

I would like to update an old table that have a composite primary key. In order to generate a full update query such as:

```
UPDATE foos SET (...) WHERE pk1 = ? AND pk2 = ?;
```

Instead Eloquent tries to do the following which does massive update:

```
UPDATE foos SET (...) WHERE pk1 = ?;
```

I set the primary key attribute to `null` as seen on Google:

```
class Foo extends Model {
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $primaryKey = null;
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: 
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause' 
(SQL: update `previews` set `preview_id` = 1805 where `` is null) in 
./vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php on line 664
```

I suppose this is not a supported feature of Eloquent, so how can I generate my `update` query?

My update query was:

```
    $p = Foo
        ::where('pk1', $foo)
        ->where('pk2', $bar)
        ->first();

    $p->update('column', 42);
```

Comment: What's your `UPDATE` query?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't fetch the model, update it directly in the database:

```php
Foo::where('pk1', $foo)
    ->where('pk2', $bar)
    ->update(['column' => 42]);
```

Comment: Yeah this is a workaround, but it will not solve queries such as `updateOrCreate` which fetches the model first.

Comment: Laravel doesn't support composite primary keys.