# Laravel 6.x - How to handle no primary key?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have a JOIN table with no primary key

```
activity_log_muscles
-> activity_log_id
-> muscle_group_id
```

I am currently defining my Model, and the documentation says to set whether my primary key is auto-increment, the field type and/or what field it is, but it doesn't say anything about what to do if there isn't a primary key... https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent

```
protected $primaryKey = 'primary_key_id';
public $incrementing = false;
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

I read the following question, and the guy says to set it to null, but he also says that throws an error... [Laravel Eloquent no primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53871297/laravel-eloquent-no-primary-key)

Any idea what I should do if I dont have a primary key?

Comment: Generally, for a JOIN (or pivot) table, you don't create a model. You would have a model for `ActivityLog` and `MuscleGroup`, and using the relationships, you'd never have to directly reference anything on `activity_log_muscles`, so you wouldn't need a model. If you do (there are use cases where a pivot table has a model, but they're rare and generally not the best approach), then you need to add a primary key.

Comment: @TimLewis Hi Tim, Thank you for your response, Is there any chance you can give me an example of what a method might look like inside ActivityLog and/or MuscleGroup that would retrieve data from activity_log_muscles?

Comment: It can all be seen in the documentation; https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many. In `MuscleGroup`, you'd have a `public function activityLogs(){ return $this->belongsToMany(ActivityLog::class, 'activity_log_muscles'); }`, and in `ActivityLog`, you'd have `public function muscleGroups(){ return $this->belongsToMany(MuscleGroup::class, 'activity_log_muscles'); }`. Then, you'd be able to retrieve this information using `$muscleGroup->activityLogs`, and `$activityLog->muscleGroups`, and manage it with `attach()`, `detach()` and `sync()` methods. Again, all in the docs.